# libcurl cookie expiry on android

Tags: c++, http, cookies, libcurl

I am seeing weird behavior with libcurls cookie engine under android, while it works properly in iOS.

The parsing of the cookies expiry date seems not to work in Android when the expiry year is 2038 or higher. I am aware of the int overflow problem with unix timestamps, but that should only occur on January 19th of 2038. With libcurl, as soon as I go to January 1st 2038 00:00 AM the issue occurs.

The following is not the exact original code, because that is more complex. But the cookie strings and curl calls are exactly the same.

```
// ...create the curl handle...

// Add test cookies in Set-Cookie syntax, because the issue seems to have to do with expiry parsing
static const std::string border = "Tue, 19-Jan-2087 03:14:08 GMT";
static const std::string borderP1 = "Fri, 01-Jan-2038 00:00:00 GMT";
static const std::string borderM1 = "Thu, 31-Dec-2037 23:59:59 GMT";
curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_COOKIELIST, ("Set-Cookie: my1=border;Domain=10.101.32.24;Path=/;Expires=" + border).c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_COOKIELIST, ("Set-Cookie: my2=borderP1;Domain=10.101.32.24;Path=/;Expires=" + borderP1).c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_COOKIELIST, ("Set-Cookie: my3=borderM1;Domain=10.101.32.24;Path=/;Expires=" + borderM1).c_str());

// Add another cookie in netscape syntax to compare (this one expires on July 10, 3145 9:20:00 AM)
curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_COOKIELIST, "10.101.32.24\tFALSE\t/\tFALSE\t37095873600\ttest\tcookie")

// Code to print all cookies known to curl for test purposes:

struct curl_slist *cookies;
curl_easy_getinfo(curlHandle, CURLINFO_COOKIELIST, &cookies);
for (auto c = cookies; c; c = c->next) {
    LogStream::debug("Cookie") << c->data;
}
curl_slist_free_all(cookies);
```

The resulting lines in the log look like this:

```
Cookie: 10.101.32.24    FALSE   /   FALSE   0   my1 border
Cookie: 10.101.32.24    FALSE   /   FALSE   0   my2 borderP1
Cookie: 10.101.32.24    FALSE   /   FALSE   2145916799  my3 borderM1
Cookie: 10.101.32.24    FALSE   /   FALSE   37095873600 test    cookie
```

So for the first 2 cookies, which are year 2038 or older, the expiry results in 0. This means they are treated as session cookies, which is bad for me. Weirdly, this does not seem to be caused by 32 bit int overflow, because with the netscape syntax, much larger expiry values are supported.

I can't share the exact build setup for libcurl, but it was derived from the scripts used here and is still fairly similar: https://github.com/gcesarmza/curl-android-ios . We use this setup to build iOS and Android binaries of libcurl (version 7.62.0). Again, with the iOS binaries it works fine (all cookies have correct expiry).

In the actual code I also validate the return of `curl_easy_setopt` and it's successfull. If you need more of the setup code I can try to put together a more complete example, but it will take a bit of time.

Does anyone know what could cause this?

Comment: Can you see if `curl_getdate` exhibits the same problem? And what `sizeof(time_t)` is on Android?

Comment: @Botje thanks a lot, I didn't know `curl_getdate` existed. Yes, it has the same issue and the docs say it returns -1 for any year > 2037 if `sizeof(time_t)` is 32 bit. Which it is for android. If you post an answer to this effect, I will accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`curl_setopt` calls `Curl_cookie_add`, which in turn calls `curl_getdate` for "Set-Cookie"-style input.
This function eventually ends up [here](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/c9c5304dd4747cbe75d2f24be85920d572fcb5b8/lib/parsedate.c#L511) with the following code:

```
/* a signed 32 bit time_t can only hold dates to the beginning of 2038 */
if(yearnum > 2037) {
  *output = TIME_T_MAX;
  return PARSEDATE_LATER;
}
```